# jQuery toggle text color from self and removing from others

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm new to jQuery/js, and I'm trying to toggle colors on click with jQuery.
I need something like this:

When I click an item, it toggles a class to change color.
If I click an item once, it changes color. Then if I click another item it changes color, but the other items must return to their initial color.

I can manage to toggle each item color, but I'm unable to remove the class color from the others.

Only the `<li>` with the class submenu-toggler should change colors. The 2nd level `ul` should not have their `li`s changed.
The final code looks something like this:

```js
$(".submenu-toggler a").click(function(){
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('red');
  $(this).toggleClass("red");
});
```

```css
a {
  color: gray;
}

.red {
  color: red; 
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="main-nav-menu" class="menu-hide">
  <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
  <li class="submenu-toggler">
    <a href="#" class="sub-toggler-a">Toggler<span></span></a>
    <ul id="submenu-1" class="main-nav-submenu">
        <li><a href="#">sub1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sub2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sub3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sub4</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
    <li class="submenu-toggler">
      <a href="#" class="sub-toggler-a">Toggler<span></span></a>
      <ul id="submenu-2" class="main-nav-submenu">
          <li><a href="#">sub1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">sub2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">sub3</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Item6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for, by using [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) all what you have to do is to remove class `.red` from the siblings elements and then perform the toggle on the current clicked element

**Update**: its working now for other elements, note that I added a selector `.red *` to make sub-elements also colored in red:

```js
$(".item").click(function(){
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('red');
  $(this).toggleClass("red");
});
```

```css
li { 
  color: grey;
}

.red,
.red *{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="item"><a>Item 1</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a>Item 2</a></li>
  <li class="item">
    <a>Item 3</a>
    <span>AA</span>
    <ul>
      <li>AA</li>
      <li>AA</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>



<ul id="main-nav-menu" class="menu-hide">
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
  <li class="item submenu-toggler">
    <a href="#" class="sub-toggler-a">Toggler<span></span></a>
    <ul id="submenu-1" class="main-nav-submenu">
        <li><a href="#">sub1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sub2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sub3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sub4</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
    <li class="item submenu-toggler">
      <a href="#" class="sub-toggler-a">Toggler<span></span></a>
      <ul id="submenu-2" class="main-nav-submenu">
          <li><a href="#">sub1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">sub2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">sub3</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item"><a href="">Item6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need, however I can't seem to make it work on my final code. I have more siblings inside the <li>, besides the  <a>...like a <span> and another <ul>. Maybe that's why I can't make it work here?

Comment: Can you add an example of non-working HTML, that would help addressing the issue.

Comment: I updated my answer, you will note that there is a new selector to color red all sub-elements.

Comment: Glad to Help :)